# How to get all coordinates of stroke on <canvas> WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, coordinates, stroke, inkmanager

I am writting an application where I have  hooked in with InkManager.
User can draw anything on that canvas, I want to capture the stroke information.
How do I get a list of all the coordinate which made the stroke?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

look into Inkcanvas.Strokes collection. you can iterate though it and get coordinates if your using WPF